# Azure Data Factory copy activity error "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When using [Data consistency feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-data-consistency) with On Prem SQL Server as source, getting the following copy activity error:

> "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS
> validated cryptographic algorithms"

Comment: Please try:  To correct this disable the "Local Security Setting System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" policy in Windows.
1. Go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy. The Group Policy dialog appears.  2. Under the "Local Policies" heading, select "Security Options" and look for the entry, "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing."  3.If entry this is enabled, disable it.

Comment: @LeonYue Thanks. But what are the obligations if we disable this option. Does that means the machine is out of compliance from security perspective ?

Comment: you're welcome. Is the error solved now? I'm not sure for this question, but I will search that.

Comment: Hi @Dadwals, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @LeonYue for sure I will do that, just that I am actually waiting for an official answer from the pg team to confirm if the above is the right approach to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and find the common solution:

To correct this disable the "Local Security Setting System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" policy in Windows.

1. Go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security
   Policy. The Group Policy dialog appears.
2. Under the "Local Policies" heading, select "Security Options" and look for the entry, "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing."
3. If entry this is enabled, disable it.

About your another question, you could ref this document: [System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-cryptography-use-fips-compliant-algorithms-for-encryption-hashing-and-signing). Maybe it can gives you the answer about this setting.

**Update:**

Thanks for your sharing.

Here's the two solutions recommended by PG team:

**Solution 1**

To correct this disable the "Local Security Setting System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" policy in Windows.

1. Go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security
   Policy. The Group Policy dialog appears.
2. Under the "Local Policies" heading, select "Security Options" and
   look for the entry, "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant
   algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing."
3. If entry this is enabled, disable it.

About your another question, you could ref the following documents:

- [System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption,
  hashing, and signing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-cryptography-use-fips-compliant-algorithms-for-encryption-hashing-and-signing)
- [Why We’re Not Recommending “FIPS Mode” Anymore.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/why-we-8217-re-not-recommending-8220-fips-mode-8221-anymore/ba-p/701037)

Maybe it can gives you the answer about this setting.

**Solution 2**

On the other hand, if this is a mandatory requirement, and you want to bypass the error and let ADF go, please follow these steps:

1. Open SHIR install folder, usually it is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared".
2. Open "diawp.exe.config", add `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>`
   before `</runtime>`.
3. Restart SHIR machine. The config file should like:

[image]

Comment: I am pasting another Answer Description: Can you edit your answer above with that content. Once done I will mark you Answer and will delete my description later on. Thanks

Comment: @Dadwals Sure, thanks,very much!